# Having some trouble with C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a program to check if a number between 1 and 9999999 is a number whose digits either stay the same or increases from left to right(The variable and function names are in Vietnamese)

```
   #include<stdio.h>
    int daykhonggiam(int n)
    {
        while (n>=10)
    {
            int donvi=n%10;
            n=n/10;
            if(donvi<n%10)
            {
                return 0;
            }
    }
    return 1;
    }
    int main(void)
    {
        for(int i=1;i<=9999999;i++)
                {
                    if(daykhonggiam(i)==1)
                    printf("%d\n",i);
    }
    }
```

The problem is, when i compile and run the code ,only some of the results were shown( the results from 5555999 to 9999999 ). when i hit f9 i can the the results run from 1 but the  final screen only shows from 5555999 to 9999999. I tried an online compiler and all the results were shown.
So i guessing my dev c++ 5.11 is the problem here. Is there any chance any of you know why that's the case ?

Comment: Have you debugged to see where the data becomes wrong?

Comment: Maybe your console window just shows a limited number of lines. Try storing the output to a file. Or try for smaller numbers first.

Comment: Also: Your program is written in C and not C++ ...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `printf` just fills console buffer completely and old lines get removed. Try writing results to file or increase console buffer capacity somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Open your terminal, click the top left corner, go to properties, and increase your buffer size. Save, and test. Repeat if needed.

That being said, I concur with previous comments that you should just use an output file.

Edit: After some testing, I could only get a max number of 9,000 lines to display concurrently. I'd pursue using an output file in your case.